# Finding the minimum distance between any pair of equal elements in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, vector

Given some array of integers A = [a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>], find the minimum distance between a<sub>i</sub> and a<sub>j</sub> such that a<sub>i</sub> = a<sub>j</sub> and i != j (or indicate that no such indices exist).

So I've implemented a naive O(n<sup>2</sup>) approach in C++, involving iterating through the array looking for equal elements and updating the minimum distance appropriately:

```
#include <vector>
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>

int MinPair(const std::vector<int>& nums)
{
    int ret = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    for(int i = 0; i != nums.size(); ++i)
    { 
        for(int j = 0; j != i; ++j)
        { 
            if(nums[i] == nums[j])  
                ret = std::min(ret, i - j);
        }
    }

    if(ret == std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) 
        return -1;

    return ret;
}
```

This works well, but I was told that a more "efficient" implementation exists involving std::map, without much clarification on what is more efficient. Namely, one could walk through the input array and store the first occurrence of an element within a map, and for every subsequent occurrence find the distance between that occurrence and the first index of that element in the map. If that distance is less than the current minimum, then we update that minimum.

However, I fail to see in what way this is more "efficient." Time complexity-wise, you would still have to walk through the input array (O(n)), and using std::map::find to identify whether or not an element is the first occurrence or not is also O(n), giving a total complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>). Space complexity-wise you have to store a map in addition to the array/vector. What exactly am I missing here?

**EDIT:** I incorrectly assumed map::find was O(n); insertion and find operations are in fact O(log n), which one can immediately see even assuming basic implementations using something like binary search.

Comment: "using std::map::find to identify whether or not an element is the first occurrence or not is also O(n)" are you sure? documentation says: "Complexity: Logarithmic in size."

Comment: Keep the array sorted and you can search for duplicates in O(n) time.

Comment: Is your container sorted or unsorted before the search?

Comment: @arekolek you're right, it is indeed logarithmic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I originally posted a coding solution that was similar to the solution mentioned by grigor.  Then I realized there was an obvious optimization that makes the whole thing work in O(N) time for best case and average case.

```
typedef pair<bool, int> LastPositionFound;

int MinPair(const std::vector<int>& nums)
{
    unordered_map<int, LastPositionFound> table; // maps value found in array to the last position that value was seen at.
    int best_distance = -1;

    for (size_t index = 0; index < nums.size(); index++)
    {
        int value = nums[index];
        LastPositionFound& lpf = table[value];  // returns {false,0} if not found
        if (lpf.first)
        {
            int distance = index - lpf.second;
            if ((distance < best_distance) || (best_distance == -1))
            {
                best_distance = distance;
            }
        }

        // update reference to hash table entry
        lpf.first = true;
        lpf.second = index;
    }
    return best_distance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map each element to a set of its indices. So you'd have something like a `map<int, set<int>> m`, and go through your vector: `for(int i = 0, i < nums.size(); ++i) m[nums[i]].insert(i)`. After that you can iterate through the map and if an element has more than one index find the minimum distance between indices. Should be O(nlog(n)).

Comment: Whats the point of keeping all the values? Its sufficient to compare the index of a duplicate element with the index of previous occurrence. And why `O(n log n)`? Both maps and sets have average-runtime for insertion of `O(1)`.

Comment: @Paul (Ordered) sets and maps in C++ have O(log n) operations. C++ also has unordered maps for expected O(1) complexity.

Comment: @Paul The question is tagged C++ and the answer mentions `map` and `set`, which are the names of ordered container classes in the C++ standard API with O(log n) complexity for operations.